# Need help on part b of this trigonometric question.

Tags: graphing-functions, trigonometric-series

The title of the question is: Using graphical technique determine the single wave resulting from a combination of two waves of the same frequency and then verify the result using trigonometrical formula

Already done part a, I'm on part b now, I have no idea what to do. If you can't read anything on the picture I can clarify it for you.

[image: http://imgur.com/penY5HN]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sum-difference formula for $\sin$:

$$\sin(\alpha \pm \beta) = \sin\alpha \cos\beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta$$

Use the sum ($+$) when two angles are being added, and difference $(-)$ when two angles are being subtracted.

---

Added: For your equations, you might also like to know that you can distribute the scalar A. E.g.

$$v_1 = \;A\sin(\omega t + \phi_1) = A(\sin\omega t \cos\phi_1 + \cos \omega t \sin \phi_1) = A\sin\omega t \cos\phi_1 + A \cos \omega t \sin \phi_1$$

Comment: Oh, I see. but what do I do with the phase shift? Would I just leave it it out of the equation? Also how does this verify it? Thanks for replying quickly. (Sorry I missed some lessons for health reasons)

Comment: Do you mean the constants $A, B$? Those would distribute over the sums: e.g. $$\;A\sin(\alpha + \beta) = A(\sin\alpha \cos\beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta) = A\sin\alpha \cos\beta + A \cos \alpha \sin \beta$$

Comment: What would happen to the B constant? Would it be something like:

Asin(α+β)=AsinαBcosβ+AcosαBsinβ

Comment: no...you'd use A on $v_1$, and use B on $v_2$, (like you apply A on $v_1$, giving you a *different* angle sum.)

Comment: I've done the first formula (see answer) $v_1$, using $A, \omega, \phi_1$. Now do the same with $v_2$ using $B$ instead of $A$, and $\phi_2$ instead of $\phi_1$

Comment: done, Oh I understand now. so when I calculate them for both V1 and V2 I presume you would add them? How does this verify my graph?

Comment: When you've got both vectors, and add them, you'll be able to do a little factoring...then graph it ($v_1 + v_2$) and confirm it's the same graph as your original.

Comment: silly question, what do I do with "t"? since it's a variable? Just leave it?

Comment: Keep it...it's the variable. You need the variable, like you'd need x, when graphing a function.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback and discourse. +1

Comment: @amWhy: Hello! Amy. +1

Answer (score 0):

It gets hard to read there, but I think they want you to use the formula

$\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a) $

Comment: Oh, I see. but what do I do with the phase shift? Would I just leave it it out of the equation? Also how does this verify it? Thanks for replying quickly. (Sorry I missed some lessons for health reasons)

Comment: In the above expression, replace $b$ with your phase shift $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$ and $a$ with $\omega t$.